# XPath Expression - Replace white spaces

Tags: xpath, removing-whitespace

I want to replace all white spaces that comes in between a string by `%20` in an XPath expression. Please let me know how to do this. I tried using `normalize-space` but this removes only leading and trailing white spaces. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace all white spaces that comes in between a string by %20 in an XPath expression.

### XPath 2.0

Use  **[replace($s, $pattern, $replacement)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)**:

```
replace(/path/to/it, '\s', '%20')
```

Or, as Michael Kay helpfully noted, consider [**`encode-for-uri($uri-part)`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-encode-for-uri), which performs this substitution among other [URI escaping rules (RFC 3986, section 2)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

### XPath 1.0

You'll need help from the hosting language such as XSLT, Java, C#, Python, etc.

---

> I tried using normalize-space but this removes only leading and trailing white spaces.

**Correction**: `normalize-space()` removes leading and trailing whitespace, *and* consolidates each interior sequence of whitespace characters to single space characters.